# JWT Token returns invalid credentials

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, jwt

I updated from Symfony 5.3 to Symfony 5.4 and everything that has to do with security seems to have changed.

I was wondering why i get a 401 with Invalid Credentials. Even tho my user is found when i dump my auth.

Here is my AuthTokenProvier

```
  <?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserAuthTokenRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UserNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class AuthTokenUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var UserAuthTokenRepository
     */
    private UserAuthTokenRepository $userAuthTokenRepository;

    /**
     * BraddiveUserProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param UserAuthTokenRepository $userLoginTokenRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        UserAuthTokenRepository $userLoginTokenRepository
    ) {
        $this->userAuthTokenRepository = $userLoginTokenRepository;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $credential
     *
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $credential): UserInterface
    {
        return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($credential);
    }

    /**
     * method
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     *
     * @return UserInterface|User
     */
    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        /**
         * @var $user User
         */
        return $this->userAuthTokenRepository->findByAuthToken($user->getUserAuthToken()->getAuthToken());
    }

    /**
     * method
     *
     * @param string $class
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsClass(string $class): bool
    {
        return $class === self::class;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the user for the given user identifier (e.g. username or email).
     *
     * This method must throw UserNotFoundException if the user is not found.
     *
     * @throws UserNotFoundException
     */
    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
    {

        $user = $this->userAuthTokenRepository->findByAuthToken($identifier);

        if (($user instanceof User) === false) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Invalid Credentials');
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

In which when i dump my `$user` I find him.
But when i try to use /api/login I get a 401 Invalid credentials.

And Im not sure why it is.

Here are my JWT yml Configs

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
token_ttl: 2592000 # token TTL in seconds, defaults to 1 hour
user_identity_field: token
```

And here is my security bundle

```
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true

password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\BackendUser:
        algorithm: auto
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\BackendUser
            property: email
    auth_token:
        id: App\Security\AuthTokenUserProvider
    jwt:
        id: App\Security\JwtUserProvider

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        provider: auth_token
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator

    api:
       pattern:   ^/api
       stateless: true
       provider: jwt
       custom_authenticators:
           - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

    easy_admin:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\EasyAdminAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # Easy Admin Routes
    - { path: ^/admin/login,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin,            roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # Api Routes
    - { path: ^/api/login,        roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/api,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    # Translations
    - { path: ^/translations,                   roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/translations/grid,              roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

If anyone could tell me what the Problem is or how i can debug better please let me know

Update:

I tried

```
      guard:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
```

Now it says

```
     Unrecognized option "authenticators" under "security.firewalls.guard". Available options are "access_denied_handler", "access_denied_url", "anonymous
  ", "context", "custom_authenticators", "entry_point", "form_login", "form_login_ldap", "guard", "host", "http_basic", "http_basic_ldap", "json_login"
  , "json_login_ldap", "jwt", "lazy", "login_link", "login_throttling", "logout", "methods", "pattern", "provider", "remember_me", "remote_user", "requ
  est_matcher", "required_badges", "security", "stateless", "switch_user", "user_checker", "x509".
```

When i try with custom_authenticators (like it says above)

like so

```
        guard:
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
```

I get

```
  Unrecognized option "custom_authenticators" under "security.firewalls.api.guard". Available options are "authenticators", "entry_point", "provider".
```

Does this make any sense ?

Comment: Just speculating here.  Back in 5.1 Symfony introduced a [new authentication system](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-updated-security-system) meant to replace the existing guard based system. Having `enable_authenticator_manager: true` means you are using the new system.  Have you checked the lexik docs to confirm it supports the new system?  Did you have `enable_authenticator_manager: true` in your working 5.3 version?

Comment: No I did  not have `enable_authenticator_manager: true` in my old system.

I Can't do that because

  Custom authenticators are not supported when "security.enable_authenticator_manager" is not set to true.

Comment: So set it to false and see if that helps.  The old system (the guard stuff) will still work just fine for 5.4.  You will just need to switch to the new system for 6.x and beyond.

Comment: Can you please check my update in the post, i tried something out and it keeps contradicting itself.

Comment: Well no.  You need to use either the old authentication system or the new one.  Can't mix and match and expect things to work.  Stay with your working 5.3 security configuration or else consider making a new 5.4/6.0 project and then add just enough code to test the authentication.

Comment: Ah okay well i can't use the 5.3 because i'm on smyfony 5.4

Comment: 5.3 and 5.4 are 100% compatible so yes you can. The new authentication system is optional in 5.4.  The old one will work just fine.  It's not until you make a major version upgrade (5 to 6 for example) that you will have to change your code.  Good luck.

Comment: Not true, because for example I had to implement the new AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator and UserPasswordHasherInterface which do not work in 5.3 anymore and this causes everything else to have a ripple effect down.

Comment: It's an interesting discussion though I feel we are close to an impasse.  I'm guessing you used make:auth after setting enable_authenticator_manager to true?  So the command generated classes based on the new system.  Set it back to false and make:auth will give you different classes to customize.  Going back to the original question did you ever research to see if lexik supports the new system?  The fact that you have multiple firewalls does not help to diagnose the actual problem.

Comment: i was having the same problem, but in my case it was just the security.firewalls alignment that was wrong (yours seems correct)

```
firewalls:
   register:
   //** all config
   auth:
   //** all config
     api: (cause error)
```